# How do I make Hinge Joints, like an elbow or knee, restricted in rotation, but have IK?

Tags: animation, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I'm fairly new to animating in Blender, so I figured it was about time I learn more about constraints and switching between IK and FK. I just recently figured out how to switch between IK and FK, and began to mess with the elbow and knee bones by adding rotation limits to make animating easier. However, when I switch to IK, the constraints have no effect, as seen here:
https://gyazo.com/6a118a8fa42dae2daa47c08ac4ab6e31

I'm not sure what I should be doing since the limit constraint works in FK just fine:
https://gyazo.com/3fb9db05ad9c6ce57e95be0446034b1d

So, if possible, can anyone show me how to make IK have the same effect as the limiter has in FK?

Comment: If you're talking about limiting the rotation of the bones once in IK, you need to select the bone, go in the Properties panel > Bone > Inverse Kinematics, and lock on the angles you want, is it what you want?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/armatures/bones/properties/inverse_kinematics.html